# Output 'NaN' Incrementing state value by using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button

In React I am trying to make a button increment a value stored in state. However using the code below function. When I click "minusbutton" or "plusbutton" and the output is 'NaN' when using `buttonplus_quantity` and `buttonminus_quantity`.

Here is my code:

```
class EnterOrder extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.buttonplus_quantity = this.buttonplus_quantity.bind(this);
      this.buttonminus_quantity = this.buttonminus_quantity.bind(this);

      this.state= {
          num_quantity :0
      }

      buttonplus_quantity=()=>{
      this.setState({num_quantity: this.state.num_quantity +1});
      console.log("a");
    }

    buttonminus_quantity=()=>{
      this.setState({num_quantity: this.state.num_quantity -1});
      console.log("b");
    }
}
```

And the `Render()`:

```
 render(){
  let {num_quantity} = this.state;
   return(
    <Button onClick={this.buttonminus_quantity} name="minus" id="minus" 
    value="-">-</Button>
    <p id='num'>{this.state.num_quantity}</p>
    <Button  onClick={this.buttonplus_quantity} name="plus" id="plus" 
    value="+">+</Button>
    );
}
```

And the output when I click is 'NaN' like this picture below:

[image]

What I am doing wrong? Thank you guys so much for helping.

Comment: Use parseInt(this.state.num_quantity)

Comment: Rather `parseInt(this.state.num_quantity, 10)` to convert the value in state to an actual number.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping but where i can add this `parseInt(this.state.num_quantity,10)` beacause i'm adding in  `<p id='num'>parseInt({this.state.num_quantity},10)</p>` it does'nt working. sorry you, guys.

Comment: I fixed the question's code formatting, are you sure, that your `buttonplus_quantity` method implementation is in constructor?

Comment: `parseInt` does not matter due to there are no string inputs; all `num_quantity` assignments are numeric.

Comment: The code that you shared must be incomplete. Render function should always return one root element. You can't return two buttons as  the root.

Comment: @AlexisCôté Can't fully agree with you. Since React v16 it is possible for render() to return an array of elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can't rebind arrow functions. I think the problem is with your binding the functions. Here is the working pen with your code: https://codepen.io/danegit/pen/EbvopX?editors=0010
Also use [functional `setState`](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/functional-setstate-is-the-future-of-react-374f30401b6b) if you are relying on previous state to update next state, as dhilt pointed out.
**EDIT** Also you can only render just one child inside `render` the code in your question wouldn't run at all. Always paste the full code if possible.

Comment: Of course! I'm blind... The arrow functions would be just function properties, not class methods. They could not be bound to instance object in such a way the OP doing...

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor your component's code to satisfy next requirements:

1) state are being mutated via callback-based `this.setState` to avoid situation when there are some other state changes that could not be taken into the account during `this.setState({num_quantity: this.state.num_quantity++});` assignment;

2) render method is wrapped with a single root element (also it could be an array of elements if it is React v16);

3) the main point (thanks to @Dane) – providing class methods for the handlers instead of property functions (replacing the arrow functions) – to make a constructor instance `this` bindings work.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.buttonplus_quantity = this.buttonplus_quantity.bind(this)
  this.buttonminus_quantity = this.buttonminus_quantity.bind(this)
  this.state= {
      num_quantity :0
  }
}

buttonplus_quantity() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    num_quantity: prevState.num_quantity++
  }));
}

buttonminus_quantity() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    num_quantity: prevState.num_quantity--
  }));
}

 render() {
   return (
    <span>
      <Button onClick={this.buttonminus_quantity} value="-">-</Button>
      <p id='num'>{this.state.num_quantity}</p>
      <Button onClick={this.buttonplus_quantity} value="+">+</Button>
    </span>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `<Button />` component imported in this `JSX` file. I think you mean `<button></button>` and if you are not using `react 16` don't forget wrapper element in `render() return` . as you can see it's working with no problem in code snippet:

```js
"use strict";

class EnterOrder extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.buttonplus_quantity = this.buttonplus_quantity.bind(this);
    this.buttonminus_quantity = this.buttonminus_quantity.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      num_quantity: 0
    }
  }

  buttonplus_quantity = () => {
    this.setState({
      num_quantity: this.state.num_quantity + 1
    });
    console.log("a");
  }

  buttonminus_quantity = () => {
    this.setState({
      num_quantity: this.state.num_quantity - 1
    });
    console.log("b");
  }
  
  render() {
    let {num_quantity} = this.state;
    return ( 
      <div>
        <button onClick = {this.buttonminus_quantity} name = "minus" id = "minus" value = "-" > - </button> 
        <p id = 'num' > {this.state.num_quantity} </p> 
        <button onClick = {this.buttonplus_quantity} name = "plus" id = "plus" value = "+" > + </button>
     </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <EnterOrder / > , document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id="app"></div>
```